# PHP creates files with the wrong user/group when run with `su -c`

Tags: php, permissions, alpine-linux

I have a user / permission issue that I can't seem to figure out.
For some context, my test environment is running PHP 8.1 on Alpine Linux (specifically, the `php:8.1-fpm-alpine` Docker image).

I have a simple `test.php` script with the following content:

```php
<?php

file_put_contents('result.txt', exec('whoami'));
```

If I execute this script from CLI as the `root` user, I get a file created by `root:root`, with the content `root`. That's expected.

However, if I run the same script with a different user (ex.: `su jack -c "php test.php"`), I get a file with the content `jack`, but the file is still created with `root:root` as the owner.

This seems wrong to me; is this normal/expected behaviour?

How can I "force" PHP to create the files with the right ownership? (`jack`, in this second scenario)

Comment: I am using `sudo -u www php test.php` on my server. Then it is `www:www-data`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I just tested using `sudo -u jack php test.php` instead of `su jack -c "php test.php"`, but the exact same issue arises. The file is owned by `root:root`, and the content is `jack`.

Comment: Maybe the directory owner where file is placed in is root?

Comment: @MarkusZeller The directory in which the script is and in which the file is created is owned by `www-data:www-data`:

`drwxrwxr-x   47 www-data www-data    1.5K Aug 18 19:50 .`

Comment: ok. Can you try `sudo -u www-data php test.php` then? Why must it be user jack?

Comment: Are you sure the script is creating the file? If the file already exists, its ownership won't be changed, the contents will just be overwritten.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Using `www-data` produces the same result. Also, I'm using `jack` to be consistent with my example from the original post; it's just to illustrate that it's a custom user that isn't related to any specific process. 

The user I am using is part of the `www-data` group, and `www-data` is part of that custom user's group as well.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I've double checked and the script is indeed creating the file. The file doesn't exist prior to the script's execution.

Comment: Those directory permissions shouldn't even allow jack to create a file there, unless jack is in the `www-data` group.

Comment: @Barmar `jack` is in the `www-data` group, so technically the permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Maybe you must use `php-fpm` instead of `php`?

Comment: @MarkusZeller That's for the web, not CLI.

Comment: I just tried `sudo -u otheruser php testwhoami.php`, and the file was created with the other user's ownership.

Comment: I'll try and create a super-simple reproductible repo.

Comment: What are the permissions of the `php` executable. It sounds like it may be setuid to root.

Comment: @Barmar `php` (`/usr/local/bin/php`) is owned by `root:root`, with the following permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x`. `chowning` it to `jack:jack` (or whichever other user) doesn't seem to changed anything.

Comment: It would only make a difference if it were setuid (first `x` is replaced with `s`).

Comment: Maybe it's docker related. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611289/php-fpm-creating-files-as-root-when-configured-as-www-data

Comment: Well, clearly something else in my Dockerfile or entrypoint script is causing the issue, because a simple Dockerfile with just the following a `COPY` of the test file and a user creation doesn't exhibit the same behaviour. I have to run for now, I'll get back to it in a bit. Thanks for the help already!

Comment: Try adding `USER jack` or `USER www-data` as last line in the Dockerfile. Would be nice to know if it fixes.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @MarkusZeller If I recall correctly, specifying a user in the Dockerfile as you suggested did create the files with the right user, as expected. It didn't solve the core problem of incorrect permissions when using `su` from the `root` user, but it's a valid workaround for most people, so I think we can leave it at that! :)

Comment: I had a similir problem at a friends PC on Windows. The problem was the container were created with docker compose as root user inside WSL2. After doing as normal user it worked as a glance.